# Cross compile Linux kernel module for MIPS

Tags: linux, kernel, cross-compiling, openwrt, modem

I need to cross compile the Linux kernel module `ftdi_sio` for a modem running Linux 32 bit on mips. The output of the uname command on the modem is this:
`Linux localhost 2.6.30 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 8 16:14:23 CEST 2015 mips GNU/Linux`.

The output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is this:

```
system type             : 963168_IADR
voice type              : SI32261
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom4350 V8.0
BogoMIPS                : 398.33
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

unaligned exceptions            : 3
processor               : 1
cpu model               : Broadcom4350 V8.0
BogoMIPS                : 402.43
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

I downloaded the Linux kernel version 2.6.30 from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) and checked if in the `arch/mips` folder there was an architecture which supports both SMP, MIPS32_R1 and BIG ENDIAN, but there was no one. So I opened the `Kconfig` file inside `arch/mips` and updated the MIPS_MALTA architecture by adding the option `select SYS_SUPPORTS_SMP`. After that I cross compiled the kernel by using the toolchain provided by Openwrt called `OpenWrt-Toolchain-brcm63xx-for-mips-gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1`. The compilation was successful and I was able to load the kernel module, but when inserting a ftdi USB cable in the USB port of the modem it crashes and dmesg provides an error that says:

```
[  561.429000] Process khubd (pid: 69, threadinfo=8793c000, task=8790add0, tls=00000000)
[  561.429000] Stack : 00000001 c448fdd4 c4494780 866a0980 87b7c000 00000001 c448fdd4 c44901c0
[  561.429000]         00000000 80348ac8 000003e0 80117a68 802e97f0 866e6b80 8793fbb8 87820e00
[  561.429000]         8111b93c 800db590 853a0bf8 80340000 85a947a8 800a5a84 802a52e8 80076f0c
[  561.429000]         866e57d8 866ba63c 87820e00 800db590 853a0bf8 853a0bf8 00000001 800a5b4c
[  561.429000]         0000a1ff 800dbe84 866e57ac 85a947a0 8793fc50 866ba63c 8793fc50 800dbc68
[  561.429000]         00000000 866ba63c 866e57d8 853a0bf8 00000001 85a947a8 802e97f0 00000000
[  561.429000]         87b7c068 800dd010 87b7c000 85a94780 85a94780 c0cd47e8 c0cd474c 85a947a0
[  561.429000]         87b7c000 85a947a8 802e97f0 00000000 87b7c068 80181168 85a94780 80154664
[  561.429000]         00000000 00000000 ffffffed 85a947a0 c0cd4780 85a947a0 87b7c000 801547d8
[  561.429000]         802e1a70 8793fce8 866e6700 00000000 00000000 8793fcc8 80154944 80153be8
[  561.429000]         870583c0 866b0000 802e2650 85a947a8 878dd650 86fd44b8 878de000 802e9820
[  561.429000]         85a947a0 85a947d4 802ab200 80154a48 802e1a70 802ac7ec 00000000 00000000
[  561.429000]         802e9820 85a947a0 00000000 801539ac 00000000 802ab200 87b7c000 85a947a8
[  561.429000]         802e97f0 85a94780 85a947a0 801523f4 00000001 00000000 00000002 00000000
[  561.429000]         00000001 00000028 85a947a0 85a94780 85a94780 00000000 866e6a08 802ab200
[  561.429000]         87b7c000 866e6a00 00000001 00000001 85836e04 801803d8 00000002 87b7c070
[  561.429000]         00000002 87b7c004 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001388 87b7c070
[  561.429000]         85836e00 87a82c04 87b7c068 00000001 87a82c00 87b7c004 00000001 87b7c000
[  561.429000]         802e9e54 87b7c068 00000002 87b7c070 802e9674 00000000 87a66868 80187370
[  561.429000]         00000002 80154664 fffffffe 866e6700 8793fe10 87828438 ffffffed 87b7c068
[  561.429000]         802e9e54 801547d8 802e1a70 8793fe50 866e6700 00000000 00000000 8793fe30
[  561.429000]         80154944 80153be8 866bb2e0 866b0000 802e2650 87b7c070 878dd650 87828438
[  561.429000]         878de000 802e9820 87b7c068 87b7c09c 87a5fd80 80154a48 802e1a70 802ac7ec
[  561.429000]         00000000 00000000 802e9820 87b7c068 00000000 801539ac 00000000 87a5fd80
[  561.429000]         00000002 87b7c070 802e9674 8793fea0 87b7c068 801523f4 87a66800 00000000
[  561.429000]         000000bd 00000081 3138393a 31323900 00000000 87b7c000 87b7c068 00000000
[  561.429000]         87b7c000 87a5fd80 00000002 00000000 87a66800 00000001 87a66800 80179aec
[  561.429000]         0000000a 87b7c000 85348380 87a5fd80 00000000 87b7c000 85348380 8017b05c
[  561.429000]         87a5fd80 8002b9b4 00000001 8793ff28 0000000a 00000001 00000000 00000000
[  561.429000]         000003e8 803280d0 80327884 01010001 00000101 00000000 8790add0 8004fa04
[  561.429000]         8793ff38 8793ff38 87a66800 87a5fd80 00000000 87a66c00 87a5fe1c 87a5fea0
[  561.429000]         00000002 87a5fd88 87a6689c 87a5fdc8 87a5fdc4 87a5fdc0 87a5fea0 00000000
[  561.429000]         00000001 87a669e0 00000000 8017a5d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  561.429000]         00000000 00000000 00000000 8004f610 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  561.429000]         8793c000 00000000 00000000 80014d34 10008d03 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  561.429000]         00000000 00000000 45551450 75455555 054d0555 1d555544 54115154 555dd155
[  561.429000]         15195545 05547516
[  561.429000] Call Trace:(--Raw--[<c448fdd4>] 0xc448fdd4
....
```